# Асинхронная отправка сообщения на почту django

Tags: python, django, email, асинхронность

Вот функция во views.py

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Game)
def async_email_notification( sender,instance, created, **kwargs):
    connection = mail.get_connection()
    emails = []
    if created:
        data = {
            'title': instance.title,
        }
        subject = 'Tripush_games'
        html_body = render_to_string('games/notification.html', data)
        for u in UserEmail.objects.all():
            settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = str(u)
            msg = mail.EmailMessage(subject, html_body, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to=[
                                            settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,])
            msg.content_subtype = 'html'
            emails.append(msg)
        connection.send_messages(emails)

post_save.connect(async_email_notification, sender=Game)
```

Подскажите пожалйста, как сделать асинхронную отправку???!!!!

Comment: Использовать Celery

Comment: Я пробовал, долбался с ним ,но ничего не получилось(

Comment: @andreymal
Можете подсказать? Если не сложно конечно

Comment: Всё есть в документации и многочисленных статьях в интернете, если у вас что-то не получается или не понимается в Celery, то опишите конкретную проблему

Comment: @andreymal я начал в этом копатся и вот у меня ошибка от redis : Error 10061 connecting to 127.0.0.1:16379. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. Подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Откуда взялось 16379 и уверены ли вы, что этот порт кем-то прослушивается?

Comment: @andreymal ну я увидел в гайде ,что нужно постависть 1 перед 6379 и я уверен ,что порт ни кем не  прослушивается

Comment: Ну вот поэтому и ошибка. Есть такое ощущение, что вы бездумно повторяете действия без понимания что и зачем происходит

Comment: @andreymal хах , вы не поверите я и с единичкой пробывал и без, и угадайте что?) Не работает) Какие-то у вас не правильные умозаключения